# What exactly does eig output in python?

Tags: python, linear-algebra

I am trying to retrieve all of the (regular) eigenvectors as well as enough generalized eigenvectors to complete a basis from my square NxN matrix. My question is, what eigenvectors exactly is this outputting?:

```
evals, levecs = eig(Mnp, left=True,right=False)
```

The documentation I was able to find on this only says "Solve an ordinary or generalized eigenvalue problem of a square matrix. Find eigenvalues w and right or left eigenvectors of a general matrix".

Could anyone tell me if this means that my left eigenvectors are both the regular and generalized ones? I would appreciate any information.

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.eig.html)

> w : (…, M) array
>
> The eigenvalues, each repeated according to its multiplicity. The
>   eigenvalues are not necessarily ordered. The resulting array will be
>   of complex type, unless the imaginary part is zero in which case it
>   will be cast to a real type. When a is real the resulting eigenvalues
>   will be real (0 imaginary part) or occur in conjugate pairs
>
> v : (…, M, M) array
>
> The normalized (unit “length”) eigenvectors, such that the column
>   v[:,i] is the eigenvector corresponding to the eigenvalue w[i].

And from the notes section of that page

> This is implemented using the _geev LAPACK routines which compute the
>   eigenvalues and eigenvectors of general square arrays.
>
> The number w is an eigenvalue of a if there exists a vector v such
>   that dot(a,v) = w * v. Thus, the arrays a, w, and v satisfy the
>   equations dot(a[:,:], v[:,i]) = w[i] * v[:,i] for i \in {0,...,M-1}.
>
> The array v of eigenvectors may not be of maximum rank, that is, some
>   of the columns may be linearly dependent, although round-off error may
>   obscure that fact. If the eigenvalues are all different, then
>   theoretically the eigenvectors are linearly independent. Likewise, the
>   (complex-valued) matrix of eigenvectors v is unitary if the matrix a
>   is normal, i.e., if dot(a, a.H) = dot(a.H, a), where a.H denotes the
>   conjugate transpose of a.
>
> Finally, it is emphasized that v consists of the right (as in
>   right-hand side) eigenvectors of a. A vector y satisfying dot(y.T, a)
>   = z * y.T for some number z is called a left eigenvector of a, and, in general, the left and right eigenvectors of a matrix are not
>   necessarily the (perhaps conjugate) transposes of each other.